# Can't launch app in AVD

Tags: android, android-studio

I am a new  android programmer.
I created a simple "Hello World" app in android studio, but when I run it on an AVD, it gives the following error:

```
Unexpected error while executing: am start -n "com.example.ahrims.helloworld/com.example.ahrims.helloworld.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Error while Launching activity
```

**EDIT 1:**
Here is the manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.ahrims.helloworld">

<application

    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

**Edit 2:**
The following is MainActivity file:

```
package com.example.ahrims.helloworld;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
}
```

I googled it, but did not find any useful answer.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please post your manifest

Comment: Try uninstall your app, clean your build, gradle sync, unplug and replug your USB cable... and rebuilt, and run your App.

Comment: I did all that, but it gives the same error. @Elye

Comment: post package name of MainActivity

Comment: Package name is : package com.example.ahrims.helloworld; @AnkushBist

Comment: post your MainActivity code you must have made some mistake at your onCreate method

Comment: I had also faced same situation before one year . I had solved that issue also but i want from you to please post screenshot of error .

Comment: @AbdulRaheemGhani Try to Disable `Instant Run` from your `Android Studio` under `Build > Execution`.

Comment: I have posted the error message.@shubhamsharma

Comment: I disabled that, but the same error repeats.@jaydroider

Comment: I am waiting.... Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the **.idea** folder and **gradle** folder, then click "sync project with gradle" gradle files, after this process finished, you are able to run your app

Comment: I did that several times, but the same story repeats.@Daryl

Comment: instead of using "extends AppCompatActivity" ,use "extends Activity".if it runs, tell me.